# Maven parent and child pom auto-increment version using Azure devops

Tags: maven, azure-devops, parent-pom

I have multiple microservices built on JHipster which used to be built separately using Maven. Now we have a parent pom that will have all the common dependencies for all the APIs that can be built multiple times, and deploy the same version multiple times of the parent pom. All the APIs will be using this as the parent pom.
The catch is that we are using Azure DevOps for the build process, where the common artifacts are being sent to Azure Artifacts, and there the version is immutable. So if this parent pom is going to be built and packaged into Azure Artifacts, I need to figure out the below.

1. How to auto-increment or not auto-increment the version of the parent pom based on the changes done.
   ( *For this am trying to use maven-release-plugin and auto-increment the version, but if there are any best-practices please do let me know, am going with the default values as of now. Planning on using the same in the child pom as well, but not sure if this is the correct approach*)
2. How to ensure that the child projects using this parent pom will be able to auto-increment the version during release.

P.S: Earlier we had a problem where any change in a common repository, needed the developers to bump the version of the pom manually before the build, as Azure Artifacts would not allow the same version to be built and deployed to Artifacts.

Comment: maven-release-plugin is one option. Or you can use [versions-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/)

Comment: @khmarbaise I was able to package the parent pom into Azure artifacts using maven-release-plugin. I hope I can use the same in the child pom?

Comment: Hi @AK123, I also tried as `@khmarbaise`'s suggestion to use `maven-release-pugin` and `versions-maven-plugin`, but I failed too. Currently, the workaround I post in my answer is the only method I can think of. And I have already used this method many times, although it may be not the best way. Maybe, you also can have a try with my suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to generate a variable for the version of the parent pom and each child pom during the build pipeline run. For example: **`PARENT_PACKAGE_VERSION`**, **`CHILD_01_PACKAGE_VERSION`**, **`CHILD_02_PACKAGE_VERSION`**, ...

The variables can be combined by some quantities and variables (include custom variables, [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and some [expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops)). In this way, you can set up the version number almost as freely as possible.

In the **`pom.xml`** file, you can fill the **version** field with the variable name.

[image]

In the pipeline, set up a shell script, using **if** conditions to determine whether change the value of the variable.
Then replace variable name with the actual value in the **`pom.xml`** file.

For example:

```sh
sed -i 's/PACKAGE_VERSION/$(PACKAGE_VERSION)/g' pom.xml
```

After above steps, build and publish the Maven package.

For the version of the parent pom, to avoid the error caused by publishing same version number to the Azure Artifacts, you can set the version number with more node, for example, **`<MajorVersion>.<MinorVersion>.<BatchVersion>`**. The **MajorVersion** and **MinorVersion** may be not changed frequently. The **BatchVersion** can be changed or auto-increased when any updates occur in the parent package and/or child packages.

Comment: Bad idea to use sed. Better use maven-release-pugin or versions-maven-plugin....

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise, Thanks for your suggestion. The workaround in my answer is the only way I can think of. I also tried using `maven-release-pugin` or `versions-maven-plugin`, but failed to auto-increment both parent and child pom versions. If possible, could you please share an example demo or the details steps to show how to configure the packages so that we can auto-increment both parent and child pom versions. Thanks.

Comment: @BrightRan-MSFT Thank you. I was trying gitflow-maven-plugin, but I have a branch policy with allows only PRs on develop and master branches that is not allowing the plugin to merge the updated version numbers into those branches. By today I think I will fall back on your solution to use a script to get this working. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: Hi @AK123, just go ahead, and if you think my suggestion is helpful, maybe you can mark it as the solution of this topic. This may help more people who are looking for a solution of the similar questions. Thanks.